# Code formatter mismatched url tag format

Tags: discussion, support

I have asked a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546694/cannot-sign-a-pdf-with-cades-method-although-signing-it-with-pades-succeeds), which has a snippet of xml code, where a web link also exists (url tag).

[image: pom.xml code snippet]

Nonetheless, the formatter didn't mark correctly this specific tag, as it mismatched the url with a comment, because of the `//`.

Would this be a bug on the editor or did I do something wrong?

Keeping the language tag in the same indentation level produces the following output: [image]

,whereas placing it in the  default indentation level, doesn't even display the code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language prettifier/synatx highlighting uses the `lang-java` highlighter for all code-blocks due to the used [java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) *(scroll to the end)*.

If you want one code-block to use different high-lighting use the explicit prettify hint notation in just before your code-block:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
```

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>europa</id>
        <url>https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Make sure though to separate the language hint with a blank line **before** and **after** to set it apart from the code block. Your edit should look like this:

```
if there is text here make sure you have one extra blank line ...

<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>europa</id>
            <url>https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

See also the [Markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100) for a list of supported syntax highlighters.